# Rich AJAX and Struts2 based web app

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I would like to get an advice and what is the best way to do a Web Application with Struts2 using AJAX, or there may be another good way of doing this.

The main purpose is that I want to make a web app that isn't reloading the pages "physically" but only the content inside the page, it is more a Media project with a player that would play some music while users navigate the website (an example could be Spotify or Soundcloud), and it would be a complex project as time went on, so I have to be sure that I can handle all the forms data and the pages content well. Is the Struts2 with AJAX from Struts2 jQuery Project a good approach (or maybe native jQuery)? and what is the best way to do this? I only have experience developing Struts or Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate.

Comment: Also consider using some spa: http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-TheAngularJSArchetype%28struts2-archetype-angularjs%29.

Comment: Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate. it would be a good Choice I guess.. As you said its Complex project let the spring take cares of backend and struts2 will takes care of Front end..

Comment: @AleksandrM, thanks for advice, just downloaded the project and it looks nice.

Comment: @looser: S2 isn't *Front end*.

Comment: @Ferrago I always advocate plain old jQuery because it is quite simple the plugin on the other hand hides some details/uses some magic tags which can quite simply be done without.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yeah I know, What I mean you can give responsibility of front end to Struts2 since struts2 is providing rich Plugin support (Jquery plugin,json plugin,..etc)

Comment: Thanks guys, will try to follow your advice.